# Grouping dates in python

Tags: python, list, date

I'm extremely new to python and I need to be able to do this without importing any modules. I have a csv file that contains Covid 19 data and I want to be able to calculate the mean, max etc for each given month and have those figures displayed in individual lists that are in chronological order. So far I have converted each line into a list and then I have been able to isolate the country from the input with this code `

```
  for line in datafile.readlines():
     column = line.split(",")
     if column[2] == country:
```

Then that outputs

```
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '11/07/2020', '364', '27\n'] ['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '12/08/2020', '802', '28\n']
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '13/06/2020', '497', '24\n']
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '390', '10\n']
```

And I want to know how to divide these months up and then get the data for those months. So far I've tried to do the same as with the country but accessing the 3 element and splitting that by / but no success and also appending them to new empty lists but that also didnt work so help is much appreciated.

P.S: This also my first post on any type of forum or question site so please let me know if ive done anything wrong, thanks

Comment: What code are you using to split by / ? Are you escaping the slash?

Comment: Try `column[3].rsplit("/",2)`

Comment: i was just trying to split the dd/mm/yyyy by the forward slash so that I could then maybe make 01=jan, 02=feb ... and then group them in that order but since I'm very new I am not sure that that will work.

Comment: thank you, that now creates the date as a separate list so now do I make the month variables like if the month equals 01 append it to another list

Comment: I can help tomorrow if no one else has. I'm about to go to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that splitting using .split("/") works to me.

Here is an example:

```
month = {}
lists = [['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '11/07/2020', '364', '27\n'], ['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '12/08/2020', '802', '28\n'],
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '13/06/2020', '497', '24\n'],
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '390', '10\n']]

for element in lists :
    mon = element[3].split("/")[1]
    if mon not in month.keys():
        month[mon]= []
        month[mon].append(element)
    
    else :
        month[mon].append(element)

print(month)
```

The result is :

```
{'07': [['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '11/07/2020', '364', '27\n']], '08': [['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '12/08/2020', '802', '28\n']], '06': [['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '13/06/2020', '497', '24\n'], ['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '390', '10\n']]}
```